# How to have a public class inherit from private interface, without getting Inconsistent accessibility error

Tags: c#, generics, types, constraints

Here's a paraphrasing of what I want to do:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public T GetFoo<T>() : where T : class, MyInterface
  {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Class1)
    {
      return new Class1() as T;
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Class2))
    {
      return new Class2() as T;
    }
    else
    {
      return default(T);
    }
  }

  private interface MyInterface {}  // This is actually empty, it doesn't do anything except limit the types that can be passed to GetFoo()

  public class Class1 : MyInterface
  {
    // Stuff
  }

  public class Class2 : MyInterface
  {
    // Other Stuff
  }
  // there are many more such classes that all inherit from MyInterface
}
```

So, I've got a public class with a public method.  The method accepts a generic type parameter.  But I want to limit the type of T that it accepts, so that's why it's using the MyInterface.
Of course that fails to compile because MyInterface is private.  It throws an "Inconsistent accessibility: constraint type is less accessible than " error.

But here's why I want it to work this way:

Each of the Class1, Class2, etc are declared public, so that others can use them.  But I want to restrict others from being able to declare their own such classes and pass them to the GetFoo() method.  Because that will break GetFoo(), so that's why I want MyInterface to be private.

If I make MyInterface public, of course it will compile and everything will work just fine.  But I need to be able to prevent others from declaring their own classes and inheriting MyInterface and passing that to GetFoo().

I want to allow callers to do this:

```
Class1 userFoo = GetFoo<Class1>();
```

I want to PREVENT callers from doing this:

```
Class UserClass : MyInterface {}
...
UserClass userFoo = GetFoo<UserClass>();
```

Edit: Thanks for all the very fast replies.  Yes I know that's not the purpose of Interface's, it just seemed to make sense to me at the time.  I am certainly open to a more elegant solution if one exists.

Comment: If the interface is empty why do you care if someone else can see it? You can't mix private and public this way.

Comment: So... you're making it the responsibility of the caller to make sure the type implements `MyInterface`, but you're not going to give the caller a chance to make sure the type implements `MyInterface`?

Comment: Sounds like you are need the factory pattern. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx

Comment: The caller should be able to do this:
Class1 userCode = GetFoo<Class1>();
The caller's don't even need to know that MyInterface exists.

Comment: @Wedge Validation of the constraint (validation that `Class1` implements `MyInterface`) happens at the call site, where that interface is not visible.

Comment: What I DON'T want callers to be able to do is this: Class userClass: MyInterface { }.  followed by: userClass foo = GetFoo<userClass>();

Comment: @Wedge You simply cannot use an interface for that. Like I wrote in my answer, you might be able to use a combination of a base class and an interface, but with an interface alone, it's just not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. This is fundamentally impossible. By making the interface `private`, the caller effectively does not know whether a class implements that interface. But by using it in a type constraint, you do require the caller to know whether a class implements that interface.

---

What you could do is use a common base class: even though that class has to be `public`, you can prevent others from deriving from it.

```
public class Base {
  internal Base() { }
}
public interface IBase { }
public sealed class Class1 : Base, IBase {
  ...
}
public sealed class Class2 : Base, IBase {
  ...
}
public T GetFoo<T>() where T : Base, IBase {
  ...
}
```

The `IBase` interface is to make sure that `GetFoo<Base>` will be rejected. `Class1` and `Class2` are `sealed` to prevent others from deriving from those.

However, this approach can only work if `Class1` and `Class2` are supposed to have a common base class.

---

I encourage to re-think your design, though. Almost always, if your generic code has a bunch of `typeof(T) == typeof(SomeConcreteClass)` conditionals, that's a strong indication that you'd have been better off creating separate methods for each concrete type. But there are exceptions, and I won't rule out the possibility of your code being one of the exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, this would work.  But it introduces some extra mess.  Having a Base class that does nothing does seem pointless.

Comment: You are right, I think a re-design is needed.  In my original design GetFoo() returned a base class, and the user had to unbox it.  But I don't like boxing/unboxing, and I don't want the user to have to do that.  So that's why I'm trying generics.  I'm sure there's an elegant way to accomplish what I want, I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: @Wedge Separate `GetClass1` and `GetClass2` methods? Or do you have so many classes that this would become a pain to maintain?

Comment: that's a possibility, but there's actually much more than just 2 classes, so I think it would be a pain.  Besides, I really like how the generics work from the caller's perspective.  It gives them one method to call, and lets them easily get the properties.  How they will use it most of time will actually be like this: var myProperty = GetFoo<Class1>().Property1;

Comment: I think I'm actually trying to create a factory pattern, but I didn't realize it.  Except that factory's typically only create a single type.  Is there such thing as a generic factory that doesn't require unboxing?

Comment: @Wedge I don't understand what you mean by that. Boxing is actually specific to value types, but you're dealing with reference types. A generic method that requires the user to cast `(Class2)GetFoo<Class2>()` doesn't involve boxing. If you just want to avoid the user having to cast, then the `T GetFoo<T>()` you have does exactly that -- except that, as you found out, it's not possible to prevent the user from making nonsense calls. Separate methods might be automated through T4 templates, but other than that, perhaps you should just throw an exception if you cannot handle the specified type?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by unboxing.  Just accepting any type and throwing an exception would work, but that way we lose compile-time checking.  I know, I know, I'm a perfectionist ;)

Comment: @Wedge Well, those are the options, I think. You have the option of performing compile-time checking, which has its costs in maintenance. Or you have the option of run-time checking, which has its costs in user-friendliness. I don't see any other solution involving compile-time checks that reduces the maintenance burden.

Comment: I just realized I do have a string value I can switch on, instead of switching on typeof(T).  This solves one bad practice, but the overall design is still the same, and my original question/problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense at all to create a class that implements an interface and to try and hide the abstraction that the interface is offering to you.

OO is not about programming towards objects, what you are definitely trying to do, but about programming towards interfaces, and you are trying to hide them.

Better think of a different approach.

Answer (score -1):

This code works and compiles:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : class, IMyInterface
{
    public T GetFoo()
    {
        if (typeof (T) == typeof (Class1))
        {
            return new Class1() as T;
        }
        else if (typeof (T) == typeof (Class2))
        {
            return new Class2() as T;
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}

public interface IMyInterface {}  // This is actually empty, it doesn't do anything except limit the types that can be passed to GetFoo()

public class Class1 : IMyInterface
{
// Stuff
}

public class Class2 : IMyInterface
{
// Other Stuff
}
// there are many more such classes that all inherit from MyInterface
```

And Main method which works fine:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a1 = new MyClass<Class1>();
        var a2 = a1.GetFoo();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the OP already mentioned that. But this allows random third-party classes to implement `IMyInterface`, and the OP wants to restrict that to the OP's own classes.